# How to Save solidity remix.ethereum file in local disk with sol extension|How to upload/direct load on github after save on local disk?

Tags: solidity, remix

Below is my solidity code on remix.ethereum and also created token in ethereum blockchain and now i wants to save my file in my local disk and after save wants to upload on github with verified comment. please help how i can do this ?
http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&version=soljson-v0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.js

Answer (score 6):

- On the left of the Remix workspace is the "Icon Panel."
  https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html
- At the top of that is the Remix logo icon that looks like a head with headphones.
- Click the Remix logo icon to open the "Home Page."
- On the Home page, on the left is a "File" section.
- In the File section is a link to "Download all Files."
- Clicking that causes Remix to create a ZIP file with all the files in the IDE that you can save to your local disk.

Comment: "Download All Files" is no longer listed under "Files", it is listed at the top of the same page under "Quicklinks".

Comment: Tried repeatedly to "Download Backup" of my files.  Each time Remix downloaded an empty zip file.  Looks like they're not ready for prime time.

Answer (score 4):

You can copy and paste it in a text editor, then save it. There are no other options if you work in the browser area.

On the other hand, you can install

```
remixd
```

and follow the related instructions in order to have your disk available in remix, even not in “browser” area, but in a so called “localhost” which appear using remixd and which maps to your disk

To install remixd you must have nodejs and npm installed, then

```
npm install -g remixd
```

Is all required.

At the node prompt you can launch remixd and the new possibility to read/write on local disk will be available.

Comment: This seemed like an excellent idea, except partly through the command ```npm install -g remixd``` creation of a file remixd.js failed on my Windows 11 PC/Git bash command line.  Rest of the script failed, and the install failed.

Comment: Yeah, I used that for so many time without problems at the time, but understand that this instructions set may be changed during last years or you may have some general problems I do not know! Unfortunately I’m currently working on a different blockchain since years and cannot help. I’m sure you can find updates on the ethereum documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Remix doesn't seem ready for prime-time.  Tried two approaches to save my files:

1. Download a zip file from the Home page (icon looks like a brain with headphones).  Repeated attempts downloaded an empty zip file.
2. Install remixd on my Windows 11 PC/Git bash command shell.  Installation using command `npm -g install remixd` failed while trying to create a file remixd.js.  Rest of the installation also failed, and the daemon was not installed.

That only left the brute-force option: copy code from remix, create a file with a similar name on your pc, paste code into the file.

Comment: You should report those issues in their github repo https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/. I regularly use Remix on Firefox and Chrome without much trouble. I've to admit that some features are broken from time to time. In you case I'd suggest to try from a Linux VM, windows isn't used by blockchain developers as much as Mac or Linux.

Comment: The file it downloads is NOT an empty zip file, the contents are just hidden (.workspaces). You can see them with an app like Onyx.

Answer (score 1):

In newer (2022) versions of remix web, the option to download the zip file has gone but the flatten has been added instead.

**To Use:**

1- In the left-side workspace management area, right-click on the contract file (.sol) and choose "Flatten". Then after a few seconds, it asks for permission for a file, and...   Finally, it generates a flat file of your contract which means all imported references will exist in the output file.

2- A paper scroll icon will appear on the left sidebar and if you click on it, you'll see Flattener options.

3- You can simply paste it anywhere to save it as a new .sol file. If you save it, it will be available in the workspace root.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer models i think you can just flatten the file(this will copy the code to clipboard) then just use notepad to save the file with the extension .sol